# session_start errors because 'headers already sent' by the same session_start action?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to start a session in PHP in order to store data about a user ID (which will be used in mySQL DB).

However when I start the session I get the following errors:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/blah) in /Applications/MAMP/blah on line 38

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/blah) in /Applications/MAMP/blah on line 38
```

I understand that the error is saying it cannot start the session as the page is already submitted, or "header already sent" however I am very confused because the line it is referencing, line 38, IS the line that starts the session:

```
Line 38: session_start();
```

So how can it say the headers are already sent by this line and that's the error?

Here is a shortened down section of my code. To note, there is  portion of the HTML that is loaded in via AJAX using jQuery, could that be it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div id="quiz-section">
             // This part is where the HTML content loads via AJAX
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- Below PHP looks at the referral i.e how the user landed on this page -->
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO entries (referral) VALUES ('$ref')")){
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
        return false;
}

$_SESSION["sessionID"] = mysqli_insert_id($con);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>

<script>
// some jQuery here to load in the HTML content to the AJAX pane   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Look to the right under **Related**. Your question will be closed using one of those links/duplicates.

Comment: Put `session_start();` before your DOCTYPE declaration. *Morning Sam*

Comment: <?php
session_start();?> should be at the begining of the page

Answer (score 31):

You're outputting HTML before the `session_start()`. Put your PHP code above the HTML code.